# amdgpu-dkms error

Tags: upgrade, amdgpu

I have tried to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but at the end I am getting this output:

```
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.0.15-1098277 DKMS files...
Building for 5.11.0-40-generic 5.13.0-30-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.11.0-40-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms-firmware.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.0.15-1098277); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up gir1.2-polkit-1.0 (0.105-26ubuntu1.3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build/make.log` is too comprehensive to post here I think, but here are few last lines:

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build/ttm/ttm_bo_manager.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:519: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build/ttm] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1849: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-40-generic'
```

I am using a laptop with dedicated nvidia GPU, but most of the time running on integrated AMD GPU. Another problem which I have posted here recently was with no video signal from any port (usb-c, hdmi). I haven't worked that out yet, but it may be related somehow.

When I'm uninstalling something via Ubuntu Software i get a popup saying:

```
Unable to remove "app_name":
Error while installing package: installed amdgpu-dkms package
post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
```

EDIT:

`apt-cache policy amdgpu amdgpu-dkms` output:

```
amdgpu:
  Installed: 20.20-1098277
  Candidate: 20.20-1098277
  Version table:
 *** 20.20-1098277 1000
        500 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
amdgpu-dkms:
  Installed: 1:5.6.0.15-1098277
  Candidate: 1:5.6.0.15-1098277
  Version table:
 *** 1:5.6.0.15-1098277 1000
        500 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`dkms status` output:

```
amdgpu, 5.6.0.15-1098277: added
```

`uname -r` output:

```
5.11.0-40-generic
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add `apt-cache policy amdgpu amdgpu-dkms` also `dkms status` and `uname -r`

Comment: @nobody Ok, the edit is done

Comment: `sudo dkms remove amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277 -k --all` then deinstall your 2 packages with `sudo dpkg -P  amdgpu amdgpu-dkms`

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you sure it's safe? Isn't there something dangerous I should better know about as a beginner before providing these steps? Anyways thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: this packages were never correct installed, so you barely mis them. the 1, command removes amdgpu from dkms tree.  the 2. deinstalles the packages.

Comment: And shall I reinstall them afterwards? Or it will do on it's own, when I run dist-upgrade?

Comment: Will this help? https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-40-2

Comment: It worked! Thanks for yout time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Get the latest AMD driver at https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-40-2

**Update**: latest drivers at https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-23-10-3

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem the following way (your version may be different):
cd /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1620033.22.04/
sudo mv source source_back
sudo mv build source
The required config is in the build folder